# ¿Cómo guardar en una carpeta archivos creados por WriteFile?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo una pregunta. Alguien sabe ¿Cómo guardar en una carpeta archivos creados por WriteFile?.

Mi problema es que ya se como crear archivos pero se guardan en la misma carpeta donde esta mi archivo app.js. Me lo que yo quiero es que se guarde en una carpeta llama archivos.txt

[image: Mis archivos]

### Este es mi codigo

**app.js:**

```
console.time("Inicio")

const { multiplicacion } = require("../multiplicacion/helpers/multiplicar");

const argv = require("../multiplicacion/config/yargs")

multiplicacion(argv.b, argv.l)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

console.timeEnd("Inicio")
```

**multiplicar.js:**

```
const file = require("fs");
const color = require("colors");


const multiplicacion = async (base, listar = false) => {
  try {
    let salida = "";
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      const resultado = `${i} x ${base} = ${i * base} \n`;
      salida += resultado;
    }
    file.writeFileSync(`Multiplicacion x ${base}.txt`, salida);
    
    if (listar) {
      console.log("================".red);
      console.log("Tabla de".rainbow, color.bgBlue.black(base));
      console.log("================".red);
      
      console.log(salida.rainbow);
    } 
    return `Multiplicacion x ${base} creado`;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## TL;TR

Concretamente puedes utilizar `fs.writeFileSync(outFilePath, ...)` donde `outFilePath` representa una ruta relativa o absoluta al archivo que quieres escribir.

## Explicación

[`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) puede recibir como primer argumento el nombre o ruta del archivo que se va a escribir, por lo que ejecutar:

```
fs.writeFileSync("Documents/hola.txt", "hola mundo");
```

Escribiría el texto "hola mundo" dentro del archivo "Documents/hola.txt" relativo a la ejecución del entorno de node.

Así que en tu código basta con simplemente hacer esto:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
// ... imports

const OUT_DIR = "archivos"; // Nombre de la carpeta donde se va a guardar todo

const multiplicacion = (base, listar = false) => {
        let salida = "";

        for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                const resultado = `${i} x ${base} = ${i * base} \n`;
                salida += resultado;
        }

        // construimos la ruta hacia el directorio de salida
        // es preferible utilizar path.join() que directamente usar
        // directorio/de/salida/archivo.txt o concatenación "directorio/de/salida" + "/" + "archivo.txt"
        // para que no se rompa con otro sistema operativo
        // e.g (/ para *nix, \\ para windows)
        const outFilePath = path.join(OUT_DIR, `Multiplicacion x ${base}.txt`);

        fs.writeFileSync(outFilePath, salida);

        if (listar) {
                console.log("================".red);
                console.log("Tabla de", base);
                console.log("================".red);

                console.log(salida.rainbow);
        }

        return `Multiplicacion x ${base} creado`;
};

multiplicacion(10);
```

Es prácticamente autodescriptivo el código con los comentarios.
Sin embargo, algo que hay resaltar es que si la carpeta `OUT_DIR` no existe `fs.writeFileSync` lanzará una excepción por `ENOENT`.

Seguro habrás notado que quité la promesa (cuando usas `async`) que regresabas de tu función. Lo hice porque era innecesaria puesto que utilizas el método síncrono `fs.writeFileSync` (y no había ningún `await`), si se utiliza `fs.writeFile` (es lo ideal), entonces sí convendría utilizar una promesa o un callback.

Hay un detalle similar en otra parte de tu código. Te invito a que ejecutes el siguiente pedazo de código

```
console.time("Inicio");

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("hola"), 10 * 1_000 /* 10s */);
}).then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

console.timeEnd("Inicio");
```

(Mide el tiempo en que se crea la promesa)

Y el siguiente código

```
console.time("Inicio");

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("hola"), 10 * 1_000 /* 10s */);
}).then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
  .finally(() => console.timeEnd("Inicio"));
```

(Mide el tiempo en que se crea Y se resuelve (o se rechaza) la promesa)

Los resultados son muy diferentes.